# Load_Click not working in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I Have an excel worksheet which works fine on Excel 2003, however when I run in Excel 2007 onward I get a run time error exception '445', object doesn't support this action. The line it is referring to is:

```
Worksheets("List").Load_Click
```

In the "List" worksheet I have the following:

```
Sub Load_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rs2 As ADODB.Recordset, cl As String, r As Integer
```

What do I need to change to call this method?

Thanks

Comment: Why doesn't the above work now it has moved to 2007?

Comment: Why cant I call a method in the List Worksheet from another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within Excel you need to set a reference to the Microsoft Active X data objects library and the Microsoft Active X data objects recordset library.  You may find that the available libraries have changed in Excel 2007.

- To reference the library, load the Visual Basic Editor (ALT-F11)
- Select Tools - References from the drop-down menu
- A listbox of available references will be displayed
- Tick the check-box next to the required library
- The full name and path of the library file will be displayed below the listbox
- Click on the OK button

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto debug in Menu Bar > Click on Compile VBA Project  . This will ensure your code is syntax error free. If any errors found kindly fix it.
2. Goto Object Brower and search for  "Load_Click". "Load_click" should appear on sheets class which you have put the procedure.
3. If procedure is found it will be called with `Worksheets("List").Load_Click`